# How to change the background of an expandable list view child that is not on screen anymore

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In a setOnChildClickListener, I am able to change the background of a child item with `v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);` (I can't use an xml list item selector because I am doing some split screen stuff and focus gets lost) I am also able to set the color back when another child is selected. However, when a selected child is scrolled off screen, it does not  go back to the original color and when a parent is collapsed, if a child inside that parent was selected, it will hop down to the next parent and change the background of a child in there since the collapsed rows no longer exist according to android. Any tips on how to fix these bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store which item was selected, then make a custom adapter which in its getView() method returns a view with the appropriate background

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a parent view outside of the `ongroupclicklistener`. I know for the children I can do something like `View firstItem = elv.getChildAt(0)`. How do you reference parents?